# Can I use HAVING to filter for AND and OR of simple record set? (MS Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a small record set of invoices. I'd like to extract all records 180 days old and newer for a statement.  In some cases there are unpaid invoices over 180 days old that I ALSO want to display.  When I added the second AND with `(Orders.[OrderPaid])=NO)` the 0-180 days records are not displayed. The 0-180 day criteria works perfect without the `(Orders.[OrderPaid])=NO)` addition. The `(Orders.[OrderPaid])=NO)` works without the 0-180 day criteria.

The code I have tried is is:

`HAVING (((Customers.[CustomerID])=[Forms]![OrdersByCustomer]![CustomerID]) AND (DateAdd("d", -180, Now())<=Orders.[Invoice Date]) AND (Orders.[OrderPaid])=NO)`

And:
`HAVING (((Customers.[CustomerID])=[Forms]![OrdersByCustomer]![CustomerID]) AND (DateAdd("d", -180, Now())<=Orders.[Invoice Date]) OR (Orders.[OrderPaid])=NO)`

Could someone suggest the correct syntax or method?

Comment: HAVING is for aggregate function conditions. Use WHERE for regular conditions.

Comment: You likely want an OR in the mix: `Customers.[CustomerID])=[Forms]![OrdersByCustomer]![CustomerID] AND (DateAdd("d", -180, Now())<=Orders.[Invoice Date] OR Orders.[OrderPaid])=NO)`

Comment: Thanks JNevill: With the OR as you suggested, the ```Customers.[CustomerID])=[Forms]![OrdersByCustomer]![CustomerID] AND (DateAdd("d", -180, Now())<=Orders.[Invoice Date]```  is being ignored and resulting data seems to be based only the ```(Orders.[OrderPaid])=NO)``` .  So there are hundreds of records from different customers listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses are crucial here, it helps to remove the auto-generated ones and format the SQL.

```
HAVING Customers.[CustomerID] = [Forms]![OrdersByCustomer]![CustomerID]
  AND (
       DateAdd("d", -180, Now()) <= Orders.[Invoice Date]
       OR 
       Orders.[OrderPaid] = NO
      )
```

The main parentheses need to be around the 2nd and 3rd clauses (OR), not 1st and 2nd.

Reason: in SQL the priority of AND is higher than that of OR.